# MySQL - Imporst csv file into existing database

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I have a csv file I need to upload to an existing MySQL database.  The csv file is on the host, and it does not have a header row.  It is just the data for the table.  I can import the csv file in the phpMyAdmin dashboard so I know the csv file can import with no issues.  I need to do it with a command line or with a script so I can automate it with a cron job.  I have spent many, many hours trying to get it to work with multiple methods.  I have tried:

PHP script:

```
<?php
$sql = "LOAD DATA INFILE '/home/dir/dir2/file.csv'
INTO TABLE Table
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r'
(col1, col2, col3, etc.) ";

$con = mysqli_connect("hostname","username","password","database");

$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

mysqlimport command:

```
mysqlimport -hhostname -uusername -ppassword database file.csv
```

mysql command:

```
mysql -hhostname -uusername -ppassword database -e "LOAD DATA INFILE 'file.csv'  INTO TABLE Table  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'"
```

None have worked.  I have gotten the same error for all methods.

```
ERROR 1045 (28000) at line 1: Access denied for user 'username'@'XXX.XXX.XXX.X/XXX.XXX.XXX.X' (using password: YES)
```

The hostname, username, password, and database names are correct.  I can login to phpMyAdmin with them.  I also use them in other php scripts to search the data and they work fine.

I have chatted with my host and they say the options above should work.  I am at my wits' end.  Any help would be very much appreciated in helping me understand how to get past my issue.  Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: How odd that it shows `'XXX.XXX.XXX.X/XXX.XXX.XXX.X'` for your IP. It should only have 1 listed, not two, unless you added that part?

Comment: @aynber Server shows the user which was selected as matched one to the client. See the difference between USER() and CURRENT_USER(). If the account was created using IP range pattern than it will be shown. This is a norma.

Comment: I did not add the second part.  I just changed the numbers to X's.  I think the second part is the subnet mask of the host.  MySQL is running on a paid hosted solution.

Comment: Can you connect to the server with CLI using `'username'` (which is reported in the error message, without the host part, of course)? without `-e` command-line option. If true then do it and try to execute LOAD DATA - does it is executed successfully?

Comment: @Akina Just tried.  No, I can not connect without specifying the hostname.(Which is similar to the phpMyAdmin loving screen with you need the hostname too.) I get the error: ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

Comment: *I can not connect without specifying the hostname.* Do not confuse hostname (the host where MySQL is running, `-h` option) and hostpart of the username (by fact - client's IP, not specified, is detected by MySQL).

Comment: I am very sorry, I do not understand what you are asking.  I connect to the host through a terminal window with the command ssh ssh_username@arkyyn.com.  It then asked for the ssh_password and then I am logged into the host.  From there I am trying to run the above mysqlimport and mysql commands using the SQL hostname, username, and password.  Does that help in any way?  Sorry

Answer (score 0):

As I know and I did this is one of the ways you can do it :

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'YourDiskName:\\SomeFolder\\fileName.csv' INO TABLE your_database_name.table_name

FIELDS ENCLOSED BY '"' TERMINATED BY ',' ESCAPED BY '\\' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
```

> (Enclose fields iva " ) , (Terminate fields by , ) , (Escape them vai \ )

this line (FIELDS **ENCLOSED BY** '"' **TERMINATED BY** ',' **ESCAPED BY** '\' **LINES TERMINATED BY** '\r\n') depends on how you save the csv file.
So , be aware of it;

How I saved the csv file :

```
SELECT * FROM your_table_name into outfile 'YourDiskName:\\SomeFolder\\fileName.csv'

FIELDS ENCLOSED BY '"' TERMINATED BY ',' ESCAPED BY '\\'
```

> (Enclose fields iva " ) , (Terminate fields by , ) , (Escape them vai \ )

And in order to get the result you my friend can make a **VIEW** and call the VIEW in PHP after you defined everything and connected to database .

Defining and connecting in PHP :

```
define('DB_HOST','localhost');
define('DB_USER','root');
define('DB_PASS','');
define('DB_NAME','ttir');
$conn = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_NAME);

$SelectQuery = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM YourViewName");

if($SelectQuery){

$Data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($SelectQuery);

echo $Data
}else{

echo "Something went wrong";

}
```

The View :

```
 CREATE VIEW IF NOT EXISTS select_view AS
 SELECT * FROM your_table_name into outfile 'YourDiskName:\\SomeFolder\\fileName.csv'
    
    FIELDS ENCLOSED BY '"' TERMINATED BY ',' ESCAPED BY '\\'
```

After you execute the query it can be used in the PHP and be shown in different ways like **JSON** that you can use it in android too , to show to the users , or any other ways.

Thanks for reading and , **That's it!!**